# Routing Error with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml

I'm fairly new to Ruby on Rails and I'm having what seems like an easy problem but I can't seem to figure out what I have done wrong. My homepage has a button and when you click the button, its supposed to create an xml file with information from the database.

Button code:

```
<%= button_to "Create Google File", :action => :create_google_file %>
```

Controller code:

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def create_google_file    
      @products = Product.find(:all)
      file = File.new('dir.xml','w')
      doc = @products.to_xml

      file.puts doc
      file.close
  end
end
```

The error I'm getting is

```
No route matches {:action=>"create_google_file", :controller=>"products"}
```

Comment: can you show your `routes.rb` file please?

Comment: `GoogleMine::Application.routes.draw do
  get "products/new"

  resources :products

    root to: 'products#new'
end`

Comment: Have a look at Andreas Lyngstad Answer that should help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your config/routes.rb file

```
match "/create_google_file" => "products#create_google_file", :as => :create_google_file
```

And change the button to this

```
<%= button_to "Create Google File", create_google_file_path %>
```